# How to find first winning combination in Tic-Tac-Toe board?

Tags: ruby, tic-tac-toe

New at Ruby so excuse the poor code. I would like to iterate through the multidimensional array `WIN_COMBINATIONS` and check whether at least one array has all of its elements equal to `'X'` or all equal to `'O'`. If so, return the matched array. This is done through the `won?` function but it seems to only be returning the entire multidimensional array. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
class TicTacToe
  WIN_COMBINATIONS = [ 
[0,1,2], # top_row 
[3,4,5], # middle_row 
[6,7,8], # bottom_row 
[0,3,6], # left_column 
[1,4,7], # center_column 
[2,5,8], # right_column 
[0,4,8], # left_diagonal 
[6,4,2] # right_diagonal 
]

  def initialize
    @board = Array.new(9, " ")
  end

  def display_board
    puts " #{@board[0]} | #{@board[1]} | #{@board[2]} "
    puts "-----------"
    puts " #{@board[3]} | #{@board[4]} | #{@board[5]} "
    puts "-----------"
    puts " #{@board[6]} | #{@board[7]} | #{@board[8]} "
  end

  def input_to_index(board_position)
    user_input = board_position.to_i
    user_input - 1
  end

  def move(board_index, player_token = 'X')
    @board[board_index] = player_token
  end

  def position_taken?(board_position)
    if @board[board_position] == ' '
      false
    else
      true
    end
  end

  def valid_move?(board_position)
    if board_position >= 0 and board_position <= 8
      if @board[board_position] == ' '
        true
      end
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def current_player
    turn_count % 2 == 0 ? "X" : "O"
  end

  def turn_count
    @board.count{|token| token == "X" || token == "O"}
  end

  def turn
    puts "Select your move (1-9)\n"
    move = gets.chomp
    move_index = input_to_index(move)
    if valid_move?(move_index)
      token = current_player
      move(move_index, token)
      display_board
    else
      puts "Select your move (1-9)\n"
      move = gets.chomp
    end
  end

  def won?
    WIN_COMBINATIONS.each do |combinations|
      if combinations.all? {|combination| combination == 'X' or combination == 'O'}
        combinations
      else
        false
      end
    end
  end

  def draw?
    if full? and !won?
      true
    elsif won?
      false
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def over?

  end

  def winner

  end

  def play

  end
end
```

Comment: Consider defining the constant `X = ['X','X','X']`, then the there is a winner with `'X'`'s if `WIN_COMBINATIONS.include?(X)`. Similar for `'O'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] it seems to only be returning the entire multidimensional array.

There are several issues with your attempted solution:

1. `WIN_COMBINATIONS` is an array of indices. These indices are numeric, so they will never be `'X'` or `'O'`. You have to check whether their *corresponding values* are `'X'` or `'O'`.
2. `or` is a *control-flow operator* intended for `do_this or fail` scenarios. The *boolean "or" operator* is `||`. Using `or` instead of `||` *might* work but may have unexpected results due to its lower [precedence](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html). You almost always want `||`.
3. The expression `array.all? { |element| element == 'X' || element == 'O' }` checks whether all elements are *either* `'X'` or `'O'`. It would be `true` for `['X','O','O']` and `false` for `['X',' ','O']`. That's because you put the conditional inside the block. What you want is to check whether the elements are all `'X'`, or all `'O'`:

   ```
   array.all?('X') || array.all?('O')
   ```
4. Your method's return value is the result of `WIN_COMBINATIONS.each { ... }` and [`Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each) always returns the array itself (i.e. `WIN_COMBINATIONS`) regardless of the blocks' result. To get the first element matching a condition, use [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find).

Let's apply all this to your code. Given this board:

```
@board = %w[
X - O
O X -
- - X
]
```

You could get the first matching combination via:

```
WIN_COMBINATIONS.find do |indices|
  values = @board.values_at(*indices)
  values.all?('X') || values.all?('O')
end
#=> [0, 4, 8]
```

[`values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at) returns the values for the corresponding indices (`*` transforms the `indices` array to a list of arguments, so `values_at(*[0,1,2])` becomes `values_at(0,1,2)`). The block's 2nd line then checks whether these values are all `'X'`, or all `'O'`. Once this evaluates to `true`, the loop breaks and `find` returns the matching element. (or `nil` if there was no match)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll keep those points in mind. Also sorry for the bad title.

Comment: @DiegoVasquez you're welcome. Don't forget to "accept" an answer by clicking the gray checkmark. (no need to rush, you can wait some time for more answers)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach the problem:

```
class TicTacToe
  class OccupiedError < StandardError; end

  attr_reader :rows

  def initialize
    @rows = 3.times.map{ Array(3, nil) }
  end

  def place!(player, x:, y:)
    raise ArgumentError, "player must be :x or :o" unless [:x, :o].include?(player)
    raise OccupiedError, "slot is already occupied" unless @rows[y][x].nil?
    @rows[y][x] = player
  end

  # gets an array of columns instead of rows.
  def columns
    (0..2).map { |n| @rows.map {|row| row[n] } }
  end

  def diagonals
    [
      [@rows[0][0], @rows[1][1], @rows[2][2]], # lrt
      [@rows[0][2], @rows[1][1], @rows[2][0]]  # rtl
    ]
  end

  def all_combos
    rows + columns + diagonals
  end

  # checks all the horizontal, vertical and diagonal combinations
  def check_for_winner
    # checks all combos for three in a row
    (all_combos.find{ |a| a.all?(:x) || a.all?(:o) })&.first
  end
end
```

In the initialize method we create a 3*3 array which represents all the positions on the board. This makes it a lot easier since its already grouped in rows. Intead of an empty string use nil to represent an empty square as nil is falsy.

When we want to check for a winner we gather up the rows, columns and the two diagonals into an array of arrays:

```
[1] pry(main)> game.rows
=> [[:o, :o, :o], [nil, :x, :x], [:x, nil, nil]]
[2] pry(main)> game.all_combos
=> [[:o, :o, :o],
 [nil, :x, :x],
 [:x, nil, nil],
 [:o, nil, :x],
 [:o, :x, nil],
 [:o, :x, nil],
 [:o, :x, nil],
 [:o, :x, :x]]
```

From there we just have to check if any of them are all `:x` or `:o`. We don't actually have to list the winning combinations. In this case `game.check_for_winner` will return `:o`.